# Property 'match' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'IRouteParams'

Tags: typescript, react-router-dom

So, I have this old project and now I'm updating it and I've got this last issue with a `match` prop.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Layout from '../Components/Layout';
import Dashboard from '../Pages/Dashboard';
import List from '../Pages/List';

const AppRoutes: React.FC = () => (
  <div>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
      <Route path="/list/:type" element={<List />} />
    </Routes>
  </div>
);

export default AppRoutes;
```

Some more information about the List

```
const List: React.FC<IRouteParams> = ({ match })
```

```js
interface IRouteParams {
  match: {
    params: {
      type: string;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` do you have?

Comment: im using 6.21.2

Comment: Why are you using react-router-dom with react-native?

Comment: im not sure, i dont know much bout react

Answer (score 0):

Route props, e.g. `location`, `history`, and `match` are from older v4/v5 versions of React-Router, v6 removed the route props. The `List` component should access the `type` route path param via the [`useParams`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params) hook.

```
<Route path="/list/:type" element={<List/>} />
```

```
const List = () => {
  const { type } = useParam() as { type: string };

  ...
};
```

Since it seems you are new to RR6, I highly recommend you spend a bit of time in the [Overview](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/overview) and [Upgrading from v5](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5) migration guide to get familiar with all the changes (*there are a lot of them!!*).